# Automatically have links archived in the Wayback Machine

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, link-rot, archive

<sub>*In [a recent (now deleted) question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331072/399694), I proposed having a little reminder of some sort to archive links that are put in questions and answers, as they can die and much of the time there is no archive of them. TheWanderer [proposed in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331072/can-we-have-some-sort-of-reminder-to-archive-links-in-questions-and-answers#comment1079834_331072) having the servers automatically archive links for us, and I am writing this to expand on the idea.*</sub>

---

**I propose having the servers automatically archive links in the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) or [archive.is](https://archive.is/) whenever they are posted in questions and answers if they meet certain criteria.**

While posts shouldn't depend completely on having them still work, links can be really important. If part of an article is quoted in a post, it could be useful to read the rest for more information on a subject. If we archived them, this would be really nice. Here's how exactly I'd want this to work:

If you post a question or answer with a link in it that doesn't go to a page on `stackexchange.com`, `stackoverflow.com`, or any of their subdomains, the link would be opened in the Wayback Machine or archive.is. Then it would go through these checks:

- If there were no archives of the link, it would wait a few hours and then save the link if the post were still open in order to not waste resources saving links from spam, troll, and off-topic posts.
- If there were any archives but the most recent were older than a certain amount of time, it would be saved (to decrease the amount of unnecessary saving of very similar versions of pages in the Internet Archive).
- If a new link were added to a post that fit the other criteria, it would be saved.

Comment: A related older discussion: [Archiving links referenced in questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228702). (However, it's not tagged as feature request.)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that it costs money to have pages uploaded to the internet archive via an API or other automated means (if it's even possible to automate at all). Due to the huge number of pages that would be linked on StackExchange, I imagine this feature request would be prohibitively expensive

Comment: Of more use would be some manner of archive that keeps YouTube video links alive,

Comment: @angussidney well couldn't it just go to https://web.archive.org/https://example.com and then click save if there were no save, otherwise looking at the text for when the last one was from? I don't think it'd need to use the API necessarily.

Comment: @Stormblessed I mean, it is possible to emulate a web request to the save page URL... But there is a big difference between what is physically possible, and what is legally allowed by the Internet Archive's terms of service

Comment: @angussidney no, it does not cost money to upload pages to the Internet Archive. Back when I worked at IA on the Wayback, I encouraged StackExchange to set up this kind of archiving for every external reference from StackExchange. Wikipedia already does it, no money changes hands.

Comment: @GregLindahl looks like I was wrong - thanks for clearing that up! In that case, I think this would be a great FR

Comment: From the comments above it seems that the main objections have been technical difficulties and possible cost. From Greg Lindahl's comment I gather that this is actually technically possible and it could actually be free. @GregLindahl (or anybody who knows how this was done on WP) - explaining this in a bit more detail would be appreciated. (That's the reason why I offered a bounty.)

Comment: @GregLindahl - really, that's automatic? When I've added references to Wikipedia, it asked me to put in an archive URL, but I had to manually archive it.

Comment: @Mithrandir ["New URLs added to Wikipedia articles (but not other pages) are usually automatically archived by a bot."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Archiving_a_source#Internet_Archive_Wayback_Machine)

Comment: I use archive.is on all URLs that I add in my questions or answers, except ones which point to redundant or well-known information (manpages, Linux source code, Wikipedia articles, etc.). It would be very nice if links were automatically archived. Perhaps someone could contact the Archive Team (they're on EFnet).

Comment: It's automatic.

Comment: @GregLindahl no, it's not.

Comment: @Stormblessed you yourself posted a link to the info about how it happens.

Comment: @GregLindahl that's about Wikipedia links, not SE ones.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought the conversation had moved to Wikipedia. Yes, I've been encouraging SE to add automatic archiving for years.

Answer (score 21):

It's probably not the solution you have envisioned, but I have written a small userscript, [Stack Exchange Archivist](https://stackapps.com/q/8386/34061), which adds an 'archive' button to the post menu:

> [image: archive button in post menu]

It's not automatic, but that means you can decide whether archiving is useful or not for your post, and you can also archive external content in other users' posts.

You can install the userscript with
[this direct link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/master/archivist/archivist.user.js) or get the source code [here](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/blob/master/archivist/archivist.user.js).